# solving a Diophantine equation through respective congruences?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

Question:

1-Let $a,b$ be integers having the property that for any prime
power $t$ there exists an integer $v_t$ such that
$$
b\equiv a^{v_t}\pmod t.
$$
Then there exists an integer $v$ such that
$$
b=a^v.
$$

2-Does it hold with $t$ being primes not prime powers?

thanks!

Comment: [Hensel's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) might help

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Is there more context to this problem? Did you find it in a book? Do you know Hensel's lemma?

Comment: @Servaes, it is a theorem in a book about sieve methods, but I would like to know if there are more elementary way to solve it.